# How do I convert text lines to columns?

Tags: python

It's probably very simple thing but I am totally new in Python so sorry. The cas is I have a lot of files containing this type of text:

```
name1
[1.0 2.0 3.0],[1.1 2.1 3.1]
```

(the directory /data/text1/1.txt)

the other file for example contains

```
name2
[4.0 5.0 6.0],[4.1 5.1 6.1]
```

(the directory /data/text2/2.txt)

and the output should be:

```
name1
1.0 1.1
2.0 2.1
3.0 3.1
name2
4.0 4.1
5.0 5.1
6.0 6.1
```

What's the best way to do it?

I tried to write the code:

```
with open('1.txt','r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        a = line.split(',', 1)
        new_line = line[0] + '\n' + line[1]
        f.write(new_line)
```

(It's probably really stupid.)

Ex.:(it's only two lines)

```
sm_CCC1OCO1

[ 71.54252843  52.88596242  51.64903087],[ 62.07181336  44.1827499   42.9019055 ]
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. While we'll be glad to help with a specific issue in your code, SO is not a hire-a-developer service, so usually you should show what you tried so far.

Comment: do you want to save your resulting structure in a file or just handle in python?

Comment: Actually ``[1.0 2.0 3.0],[1.1 2.1 3.1] `` this is not a proper list. What exactly you want?

Comment: #1 Since I'm using python for ~1week my trials are really stupud probably, but one of them was:

with open('1.txt','r+') as f:
 for line in f:
  a = line.split(',', 1)
  new_line = line[0] + '\n' + line[1]
  f.write(new_line)

#2 I want to save it as a text.
#3 Well yes, I am sorry - I should probably call it just a text, not a list. So I want to edit this text file so it would separate to columns like in the original question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code you just posted in a comment to it.

Comment: I think you are confused in asking. Do you want text files to be transformed into list. Beacuse the way you want to put numbers doesn't appear as a list.

Comment: @NIKHILRANE (and MY Khan): The OP just said the lines were in a file, not that they contained lists in Python form.

Answer (score 1):

You can `zip` and `re` to solve your problem.
Below is the code:

```
>>> import re, os
>>> for file in os.listdir("directory"):
>>>     with open(file) as fp:
>>>         for line in fp.readlines():
>>>            lists = [re.findall("\d+\.\d+",l) for l in line.split(',')]
>>>            for a,b in zip(lists[0],lists[1]):
>>>                 print a, b
```

For file with content:

```
[1.0 2.0 3.0],[1.1 2.1 3.1]
```

Output:

```
1.0 1.1
2.0 2.1
3.0 3.1
```

Hope this is what you expects.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I want, but the problem it I have ~200 text files like this so I would like to do it it a way there's no need to put all the number in every script.

Comment: You can iterate over all the files in a directory and directly process over the contents of files viz., lines.

Comment: I got the error that for a,b in zip(lists[0],lists[1]): list index out of range.
at the third line i should put the name of my file instead of (file) or not?

Comment: @BrigitaP.: The first line of each file has a name on it, correct?

Comment: @BrigitaP: Does each file does only have two lines, first line is name and second one is list?

Comment: Yes. I've edited the question and put one particular example to the end

Comment: And what should I add to the code so the output would be not printed but saved to the original file (to change original file)?